# Way to escape from a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

I’ve had a question on WHY a traveler couldn’t “escape” from a black hole under specific conditions (I have an image I'd like to send to clarify, but the website won't let me)>

The key is for the Center of Mass for the traveler’s system to remain safely outside the Black hole’s [event horizon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon). My limited knowledge suggests that if it were a massive enough Black hole, the acceleration and tidal gradients near the event horizon might produce finite or even “low” forces internal to the traveler’s system?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the traveler, atoms, would be within the event horizon. Pulling those atoms out of the tug of the black hole is impossible. The traveler himself, I believe, would not be lost as long as he released his grasp on the trapped atoms before being pulled in entirely.